# How to disable \citep

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

I'm using Texmaker with biber. Everything works great, all references and the bibliography work as intended.
When I want to reference, I say `\cite` and get a list of suggestions, starting with `\citep{...}`.
I personally don't see any benefits in using `\citep` instead of just `\cite`, I even get an error `Undefined control sequence \citep` when trying to use `\citep`.
As the suggestion list starts with `\citep`, I have to scroll down through all my possible references, until I reach `\cite{...}`.

Is it possible, to disable `\citep`, so that my list starts directly with just `\cite?`

I know, it's first world problem, but nevertheless it would save me some time.

Comment: I can't see any way to do this. I can just suggest to use a shortcuts options -> configure texmaker -> shortcuts and find down \cite{}

Comment: If you add `natbib=true` to `biblatex`' options you can use `\citep` and `\citet`, but they only make sense with author-year citations of course. (The corresponding 'native' `biblatex` commands are `\parencite` and `\textcite`.) Also, as your question is actually just a question about Texmaker I'll retag it.

Comment: Have you considered using `\autocite`? It offers additional flexibility and would presumably make the top of the list of suggestions. (Why is `\citep` above `\cite`, though? Why not alphabetical order?)

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a way to disable the `\citep` suggestion in Texmaker, but I circumvent the trouble by adding this in the document header:

```
\newcommand{\citep}[1]{\cite{#1}}
```

This actually defines the control sequence `\citep`. All it does is to translate `\citep` into `\cite`, which compiles just fine.

As a result, you can use the suggestions in the `\citep` list and do not have to scroll all the way down.